# Swift Image conversion failed from one view controller to another controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to send the data in including image from one view controller to another . The data is fetching from API . The data is successfully loaded into first view controller including image but when I try to reuse same code with didSelectRow function I am getting following errors .  **Cannot assign value of type 'Data?' to type 'UIImage'** . **The error on this line   dc.imagemovie = presenter.getImageData(by: row).**  Here is the code to fetch the data from API.

```
class MoviePresenter: MoviePresenterProtocol {
    
    private let view: MovieViewProtocol
    private let networkManager: NetworkManager
    private var movies = [Movie]()
    private var cache = [Int: Data]()
    var rows: Int {
        return movies.count
    }
    
    init(view: MovieViewProtocol, networkManager: NetworkManager = NetworkManager()) {
        self.view = view
        self.networkManager = networkManager
    }
    
    
    func getMovies() {
        let url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?language=en-US&page=3&api_key=6622998c4ceac172a976a1136b204df4"
        
        networkManager.getMovies(from: url) { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                self?.movies = response.results
                self?.downloadImages()
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.view.resfreshTableView()
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.view.displayError(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getTitle(by row: Int) -> String? {
        return movies[row].originalTitle
    }
    
    func getOverview(by row: Int) -> String? {
        return movies[row].overview
    }
    
    func getImageData(by row: Int) -> Data? {
        return cache[row]
    }
    
    private func downloadImages() {
        let baseImageURL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"
        let posterArray = movies.map { "\(baseImageURL)\($0.posterPath)" }
        
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        group.enter()
        for (index, url) in posterArray.enumerated() {
            networkManager.getImageData(from: url) { [weak self] data in
                if let data = data {
                    self?.cache[index] = data
                }
            }
        }
        group.leave()
        group.notify(queue: .main) { [weak self] in
            self?.view.resfreshTableView()
        }
    }
     
    
}
```

Here is the code in view controller to display the data into table view cell .

```
class MovieViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    private var presenter: MoviePresenter!
    
    var finalname = ""
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        userName.text = "Hello: " + finalname
        setUpUI()
        
       // configure presenter
       presenter = MoviePresenter(view: self)
        presenter.getMovies()
    }
    private func setUpUI() {
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func selectSegment(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        
        if sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0{
        setUpUI()
        presenter = MoviePresenter(view: self)
        presenter.getMovies()
        }
    }
    
}

extension MovieViewController: MovieViewProtocol {
    
    func resfreshTableView() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
    func displayError(_ message: String) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let doneButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(doneButton)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    
}

extension MovieViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        presenter.rows
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MovieViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MovieViewCell
        
        let row = indexPath.row
        let title = presenter.getTitle(by: row)
        let overview = presenter.getOverview(by: row)
        let data = presenter.getImageData(by: row)
        cell.configureCell(title: title, overview: overview, data: data)
        return cell
    }
    
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let dc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MovieDeatilsViewController") as! MovieDeatilsViewController
        
        let row = indexPath.row
       dc.titlemovie = presenter.getTitle(by: row) ?? ""
       dc.overview = presenter.getOverview(by: row) ?? ""
       **dc.imagemovie = presenter.getImageData(by: row) // Error on this line** 
      
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(dc, animated: true)
   }
    
    
}
/*
 var titlemoview = ""
 var overview = ""
 var imagemovie = UIImage()
 */

extension MovieViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableView.automaticDimension
    }
}
```

Here is the code for display the data .

```
class MovieDeatilsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var movieImage: UIImageView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var movieTitle: UILabel!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var movieOverview: UILabel!
    
    
    var titlemovie = ""
    var overview = ""
    var imagemovie = UIImage()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        movieTitle.text = titlemovie
        movieOverview.text = overview
        movieImage.image = imagemovie
        
    }

}
```

Comment: You have convert the image into data

Comment: I am not sure . how to convert it in this case . I am reusing the code @Rasel

Comment: No I am not using viper . I am following MVVP Design pattern

Comment: the problem is that you want to asign var of type Data to UIIMage, you have to convert to object data to image and after that assign this value to your new variable

Comment: Yes . I want to display the images with other field when didAelectRow function is selected

Comment: The error message is perfectly clear. If you read the error message you will know what to do. Is the problem that you don't understand what it says?

Comment: I know it is the image data conversation. But not sure how can I convert it ? and display it to details view controller @matt

Comment: Well, if it is image data and you want a UIImage, you would call `UIImage(data:)`, wouldn't you?

Comment: yes I am not sure to configure with didSelectRow functions @matt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get `UIImage` from data in  `configureCell(:, : , :)` function by `UIImage(data:yourdata)` and assign to your imageview

```
let image =  UIImage(data:yourdata)
imageview.image = image
```